# How to create an interactive circular links using CSS

Tags: html, css

I wish to do something similar to this,
http://timheuer.com/blog/archives.aspx
i need to create a interactive circular links using CSS.

Comment: Could you describe what you want exactly? There are a lot of things on  that page.

Comment: I need only the links  appearing on the top right of the page. I cannot understand the hover effect and the drawing inside these circles. I know those are aspx pages.

Comment: It's just a CSS class replacement on hover. No magic HTML5 or CSS3 there.

Comment: It's a background image that's clipped. http://timheuer.com/blog/Skins/2012/img/navbarglyphs.png Relevant search terms: "css sprites" Apart from that, you can make these using a rounded border and a background image, a rounded border and an icon font, a background image and an icon font, an `<img>`, etcetera.

Comment: Thanks, i need  some sleep now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can achieve that effect. The page in question looks like it simply uses an image background in a css style. The simplest example is;

## 1 Image Background

```
#link1 {
    background-image: url('/images/button1-trans.png')
}

#link2 {
    background-image: url('/images/button2-trans.png')
}

#link1:hover {
    background-image: url('/images/button1.png')
}

#link2:hover {
    background-image: url('/images/button2.png')
}
```

## 1b Image Spriting

Using multiple images like requires multiple browser requests so 'image spriting' is a technique commonly used these-days to optimise the download into a single request which will then be cached resulting in a single 304 response. In Tim's case, his looks like this (although the original is transparent);

[image]

Then you use the same image for each link along with a clipping and offsetting to locate the appropriate part of the image;

```
#links a {
    background-image:url('/images/allButtons.png')
    background-position: 0px 0px; /* sets the row for all normal links */
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px; /* bounding box for the image */
}

#links #link1 {
    background-position: 0px 0px; /* first icon on the first row */
}
#links #link2 {
    background-position: -64px 0px; /* slides the image strip left to locate the second icon on the first row */
}
#links #link1:hover {
    background-position: 0px -64px; /* first icon on the second row */
}
#links #link2:hover{
    background-position: -64px -64px; /* second image, second row */
}
```

Notice the background-image in `#links a`? Well that's actually superfluous in this case, but it would be nice if you could do that, and then you would only need to use `background-position-x` in each icon and you would only need one `#links a:hover` which would set the common row using `background-position-y:-64px` but the FireFox team with their usual pedantic standards-only 'computer says no' approach decided NOT support background-position-x or y, even though every other browser does and it's in common use. Much to the chagrin of everyone who'd like to use it in this way.

However, zoom in on those buttons on the blog you linked to. See how they look all pixelated?

[image]

## 2 Pure CSS

You can achieve the circles at least with a combination of CSS `border-style`, `border-width` and `border-radius` as others have posted, but you still need the image for the center button.

## 3 Icon Fonts

## ☺☻☼☽☾☿

This is the most modern, and my preferred approach as it's fully scalable, transparent, really, really tiny and super-fast. You need to download your font of course, but SVG compresses really well. It's just text in your HTML, no images at all. No crazy CSS styling either. Checkout [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app/)! See how you can zoom all the way in on those?

Zoom in on the icons above, and Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJxNk/3/)

You can use icoMoon free, but I've purchased the pro pack, it's honestly priced and the value is well worth it. It's an awesome site as you can even load up your own SVG icons and it will generate your own font for you. There's even IE6 support.

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation. I successfully implemented these.

Answer (score 1):

**EXPLANATION**

The page You show us use a images sprit with icon of all menu item, event with border. My example show how do this with simple css. You can also use images sprit but including only icon.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
html, body {
    background: #369BD7;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
}

ul {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 100%; 
   -moz-border-radius: 100%;  
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;   
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: transparent url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/TWG_Retina_Icons/24/home.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
} 

ul li a span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**BORDER RADIUS BROWSER SUPPORT**

http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/bartekbielawa/fgPf8/6/

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have the `border-radius` be half of the `height` and `width`. Then just use a gif or png for IE fallback.

```
.round-button {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50px; /* be sure to add all the browser prefix versions */
}
```

Comment: `border-radius:50%; ` will do